# How to fix Flex basis 50%

Tags: reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

i just simply want the flex items to be 50% width and have space between them, but all i get is 1 item on each row,

```
const renderLanguageCardItem = (flag_1,flag_2,title,description) => (
        <div className="flex flex-col justify-center items-center py-4 bg-white shadow-xl basis-1/2 max-w-[50%] flex-shrink-0 flex-grow-0 md:basis-1/4">
            <div className="flex justify-center items-center gap-2 mt-6">
            {flag_1}
            {flag_2}
            </div>
            <h5 className="mt-4 mb-2 text-sm text-gray font-medium">{title}</h5>
            <h6 className="mb-2 text-xs/[1.2rem] font-medium">{description}</h6>
        </div>
    )

return (
 <section className="pt-10 bg-white pb-8">
                <div className="container mx-auto px-[15px] pt-12 mt-7 flex flex-col pb-12">
                    <h2 className="text-purple-dark">Les langues enseignées</h2>
                    <div className="flex flex-wrap gap-8 justify-center mt-8">
                        {renderLanguageCardItem(<LbFlag/>,null,'Arabe','')}
                        {renderLanguageCardItem(<FrFlag/>,null,'Français','')}
                        {renderLanguageCardItem(<UkFlag/>,<UsFlag/>,'Anglais','(à partir du CE2)')}
                    </div>
                </div>
</section>
)
```

please help , i can't seem to find the problem and that is occuring almost in every flex box i make, the solution tothis is to use basis-[45%] but why do i have to use that? and not 50%

Comment: Can you share a picture of what it looks like?
Also, understanding from what you've said "i just simply want the flex items to be 50% width and have space between them".
  
having two 50% elements and some gap between them would overflow the total width, so flex would naturally throw the element to the next line. You can either remove the gap, or use less width, say 40%